# SQL Server Store Procedure producing data related to months between two dates

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm stuck on the following problem.

I have a start range date and end range date calculated by a query and I have three columns also produced by another query, the outcome of the last query is:

```
PRJ_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE
```

I want to produce an output using a store procedure that considering all the months between start range date and end range date produces an output like this:

```
PRJ_ID | MONTHS1 | MONTHS2 | ... | MONTHSN
XXXX   | YES     | YES     | ... | NO
```

The yes or no is obtained checking if the current month is in between the start_date and end_date of the project (table obtained above).

I'm able to produce all the months between two dates with this code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```

But I'm stuck on producing the last result.

Comment: You must use PIVOT. Because the number of month will vary, you must use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur any example or link where I can better understand the solution?

Comment: google SQL DYNAMIC PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(PRJ_ID INT,  START_DATE DATE, END_DATE date)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '20110501', '20110801'),
(2, '20110101', '20110901'),
(3, '20110301', '20110401')

;WITH cte1 AS(SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) m(m)),
cte2 AS(SELECT * FROM cte1 c1 JOIN @t t ON c1.m BETWEEN MONTH(t.START_DATE) AND MONTH(t.END_DATE))
SELECT  PRJ_ID, 
        START_DATE, 
        END_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN [1] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS January,
        CASE WHEN [2] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS February,
        CASE WHEN [3] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS March,
        CASE WHEN [4] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS April,
        CASE WHEN [5] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS May,
        CASE WHEN [6] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS June,
        CASE WHEN [7] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS July,
        CASE WHEN [8] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS August,
        CASE WHEN [9] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS September,
        CASE WHEN [10] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS October,
        CASE WHEN [11] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS November,
        CASE WHEN [12] IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS December
FROM cte2
PIVOT (MAX(m) FOR m IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p
```

Output:

```
PRJ_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
1       2011-05-01  2011-08-01  NO      NO          NO      NO      YES YES     YES     YES     NO          NO      NO          NO
2       2011-01-01  2011-09-01  YES     YES         YES     YES     YES YES     YES     YES     YES         NO      NO          NO
3       2011-03-01  2011-04-01  NO      NO          YES     YES     NO  NO      NO      NO      NO          NO      NO          NO
```

Comment: I did not try it yet, but this solution should work only for 1 year, the month lists is more than a year.

Comment: Did I miss that IMPORTANT information from your question?? How the result should look like in this situation?

Comment: Sorry I did not claimed that every months as the Year associated. So the output for the month should be "Jan-2011"....."Jan-2015".

Comment: ok, what if one project is '20100101' - '20110101'  and the other is '20130101' - '20150101'? What would be the output?

Comment: I calculate the min start_date and the max end, then I have to put NO on all the months in which the project is not active that is the  months is not within the start date and end date . So the month 20100101 is YES for the first project and NO for the second for example